# cocos.layer package being reported as nonexistent in PyDev

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, cocos2d-iphone, pydev

I'm currently using Eclipse Juno, PyDev 2.7.5, and Cocos2d 0.5.5 installed through pip.

After reconfiguring the Python interpreter in PyDev, Whenever I type cocos.layer.Layer in a module, it underlines cocos.layer as an error and says `Undefined variable from import: layer`.

The strange thing is that I can see the cocos.layer package in the PyDev Package Explorer, and yet its reported as nonexistent in the autocomplete and the error detector.

Any idea on what could be going wrong here, or how I can force PyDev to recognize a subpackage?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked, but if it finds 'cocos' but not 'cocos.layer', it may be that it's something hard to analyze statically.

In this case, try adding 'cocos.layer' to the forced builtins. See 'http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html' in the getting started manual for details.